# c3.js not showing values on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm using [c3js.org](http://c3js.org/) to display some charts in my app. The problem is, that chart tooltips aren't showing any values.

[image]

> Code

```
<script>
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#designerChart',
    data: {
        x: 'Service date',
        columns: [
            ['Service date', '01-07-2016', '02-07-2016', '03-07-2016', '04-07-2016', '05-07-2016', '06-07-2016', '07-07-2016', '08-07-2016', '09-07-2016', '10-07-2016', '11-07-2016', '12-07-2016', '13-07-2016', '14-07-2016', '15-07-2016', '16-07-2016', '17-07-2016', '18-07-2016', '19-07-2016', '20-07-2016', '21-07-2016', '22-07-2016', '23-07-2016', '24-07-2016', '25-07-2016', '26-07-2016', '27-07-2016', '28-07-2016', '29-07-2016', '30-07-2016', '31-07-2016'],
            ['No. of reservations', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            tick: {
                rotate: 75,
                multiline: false
            },
        },
    }
});
</script>
```

**Question:** How can I display values in tooltips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using [patternfly.org](https://www.patternfly.org/) which overrides `c3js` styles. The solution was not to include `c3js` styles but to let `patternfly` style the graphs.

After I removed them, everything is working as expected.